# How to configure WAS to show fine log level in RAD console

Tags: logging, websphere

I configured WAS to log my class' fine messages (com.test.*=fine) in the admin console, but in RAD, the entries "logger.fine(message)" don't show up in RADs' console. Is there an additional step I'm missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two tabs: Configuration, Runtime.

If you only made the changes in Configuration and didn't restart your server instance, you won't see the changes reflected in your Console. Better to make the changes on the Runtime tab to test them immediately, then check the box to "Save runtime changes to configuration as well" when you're ready to persist your changes permanently.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; what I did was to do the change in Configuration and as it didn't work, I restarted the server. Shouldn't it have worked then?